# Scene size in Xcode 6 / SpriteKit / Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode6, scene

I've been getting stuck doing what should be really simple stuff in Xcode, I am trying to add a sprite to the scene and for it to sit in the bottom left corner:

```
var groundTexture : SKTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "dirt-block")    
var ground : SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundTexture)
ground.position = CGPointMake(ground.size.width/2, ground.size.height/2)
self.addChild(ground)
```

This doesn't show anything, so I took a look at what the scene dimensions are and self.frame.size.width and self.frame.size.height are returning a width of 1024 and a height of 768, regardless of orientation.

I want this fixed in landscape mode if that makes any difference to the answer?

I'm obviously missing a very fundamental idea to do with setting up the scene, if anybody could shed any light it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The scene size is determined by GameScene.sks. If you click on that file, you'll see the size property of the scene is set to 1024 x 768.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to edit the GameViewController:

Cut everything from `viewDidLoad()` except `super.viewDidLoad()`

Overwrite `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        var skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Also you should set the scene size as you can see

```
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

Hope this helps

There is also a great Tutorial where this is explained better:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/49721/how-to-create-a-breakout-game-using-spritekit
(Chapter 1 or 2)

Comment: Another example on the web that covers just this is http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-setting-up-correct-scene-dimensions