# Spawn enemies randomly only within the screen width

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

I started working with SKS files to create games in swift, and in this game im trying to get enemies to spawn randomly within the width of the phone screen as opposed to all over the sks file scene

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
   self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func spawnEnemy(){
   //supposed to pick random point within the screen width
    let xPos = Int.random(self.frame.width)

    enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
    enemy.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(xpos), self.frame.size.height/2)
    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 7)
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
    enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
    addChild(self.enemy)
}
```

Comment: First of all, use SKAction or update: method for spawning. NSTimer is not affected if node, scene or view are paused so it can lead to "troubles". Second, you are trying to add the same node over and over again (adding self.enemy inside the spawnEnemy method). You should create a new node, or at least make a copy of existing one before trying to add it to the scene (if you try to add a node which already has a parent, you will get an error). Also there are some typos in your code. Fix all that and see if it works. Let me know if you need a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyways, I wrote an example for you :)

So, here is how  your example should look in order to work:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

      NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    }


    func randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: CGFloat, secondNum: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(firstNum - secondNum) + min(firstNum, secondNum)
    }

    func spawnEnemy(){
        //supposed to pick random point within the screen width
        let xPos = randomBetweenNumbers(0, secondNum: frame.width )

        let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy") //create a new enemy each time
        enemy.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(xPos), self.frame.size.height/2)
        enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 7)
        enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
        enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
        addChild(enemy)
    }
```

Method randomBetweenNumbers is borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26029530/3402095).

And, this is another way of how you can spawn enemies by using SKAction:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        let wait = SKAction .waitForDuration(1, withRange: 0.5)

        let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({

            self.spawnEnemy()

        })

        let spawning = SKAction.sequence([wait,spawn])

        self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawning), withKey:"spawning")



    }
```

Method spawnEnemy remains the same in both cases. To stop spawning you can remove an action for certain key ("spawning" in this case). You can do it like this:

```
 if((self.actionForKey("spawning")) != nil){
        self.removeActionForKey("spawning") 
    }
```

Comment: the problem with the app is that the enemys arent spawning within the phone screen, they were going throughout the sks file. The frame.width thing gets the entire sks files width. I only want the range to be just within the width of the phone, thank you for your response btw

Comment: @sk8ertagsk8ertag Have you actually tried the code ? On my side it works as it should. Spawning nodes along the line starting from the left and going to the right side of the screen. Another thing you should know is that when you are creating the scene from .sks file, the default scene size is 1024x768. But I've assumed that you have properly initialized your scene (and view) size.

Comment: ya i tried the code but its still not working. How did you initialize your scene

Comment: @sk8ertagsk8ertag I will post you a link... In the meanwhile, can you be more precise ... What do you mean by "not working" ... Nodes are spawning somewhere else instead of in the middle of the screen along the line which goes from left side of the screen to the right ? Or you are getting compiler errors?

Comment: You could initialize a scene with a view.bounds.size, like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26266857/3402095