# How to change SKscene size

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, skscene

every time i run my app in my simulator the view scale always comes out to 768,1024 how do you change this to 1024,768. here is the default size code 
    class GameViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve 
rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Comment: `scene.size = ...`  and you can move your code from above from viewDidLoad to viewWillLayoutSubviews or viewDidAppear...  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26266857/1702413

Comment: There is no point putting it in to ViewWillLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Do you just want to change the screen orientation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) If you use .sks files (the spriteKit visual editor)

Just go to the GameScene.sks file (not swift) in you project where  you can change the scene size in the inspector on the right.

You can check this article here where they show this if you scroll down a tiny bit. Its a good tutorial you should ready if you plan on working with the visual editor.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/118225/introduction-sprite-kit-scene-editor

2) Not using .sks files, loading scenes in code

If you dont use .sks files you can delete the GameScene.sks file and load the scene like so.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

    // Configure the view.
    guard let skView = self.view as? SKView else { return }

    let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1080))

    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    skView.presentScene(scene)
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i tried both of your methods, neither worked i got error messages from  both. I don't think i am implementing it right. here is the default view did load code,override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
  skView.showsFPS = true
  skView.showsNodeCount = true
  skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
skView.presentScene(scene)   }     
}
 to implement the codes you provided what do i have to delete and what do i need to add?

Comment: Updated, let me know how it goes.

Comment: If you use the standard xCode game template, which is what you are doing from your code above, you are working with .sks files so you would look at method 1. If you want to do your game all in code than you can delete GameScene.sks and follow 2.

Comment: @ crashoverride777 I implemented your second option, there were no errors in the code itselff but i get a new error for all of my override functions saying "override" can only be specified on class members and "super" cannot be used outside of class members

Comment: Sorry, I put an extra { in the code at the end by mistake. Check the answer again