# SKSpriteNode bouncing of something I didn't create in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I was trying to make a square drop from the top of the screen. But when it get's half way down it keeps bouncing off the screen. I didn't create an object in the middle of the screen. I can't understand why it's bouncing at the middle of the screen.

Here's the link to a video of me running the code: http://sendvid.com/enm9l1np

Here's the code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

     var animator : UIDynamicAnimator?
     let BlueSquare = SKSpriteNode()
     let RedSquare = SKSpriteNode()
    var scorenumber = 0
    var Ground = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 1.0, dy: -9.0)

        let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        // 2. Set the friction of that physicsBody to 0
        borderBody.friction = 0
        // 3. Set physicsBody of scene to borderBody
        self.physicsBody = borderBody





        let width = UInt32(self.frame.size.width)

        let X = arc4random() % width


        Ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ground")
        Ground.setScale(1.0)
        Ground.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: 5)
        Ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Ground.size)
        Ground.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        Ground.physicsBody!.dynamic = false

        Ground.zPosition = 3

        self.addChild(Ground)


        //INizialize
        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view!)

        //Add Gravity

        //animator?.addBehavior(gravity, sprite)




        BlueSquare.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        BlueSquare.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(X), y: 1000)
        BlueSquare.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        BlueSquare.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        BlueSquare.name = "bluecube"
        BlueSquare.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
        BlueSquare.color = SKColor.blueColor()
       // BlueSquare.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)

        //BlueSquare.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, -90))
        self.addChild(BlueSquare)

        let X2 = arc4random() % width
        RedSquare.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        RedSquare.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(X2), y: 1000)
        RedSquare.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        RedSquare.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        RedSquare.name = "redcube"
        RedSquare.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
        RedSquare.hidden = false

        RedSquare.color = SKColor.redColor()

        self.addChild(RedSquare)




        var gameTimer = NSTimer!()
       gameTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "spawning1", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }



    func spawning1() {


    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch in touches {
           // let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let currentPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let currentNode = nodeAtPoint(currentPoint)
            let nodeName: String? = currentNode.name


            if nodeName == "bluecube" {
                BlueSquare.hidden = true

                score()
            }

            if nodeName == "redcube" {
                RedSquare.hidden = true

                score()
            }

        }
    }

    func score () {
        scorenumber++
        print(scorenumber)
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
       if CGRectIntersectsRect(RedSquare.frame, Ground.frame) {
        RedSquare.position = CGPoint(x: RedSquare.position.x, y: RedSquare.position.y + 10)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't begin variable names with an uppercase letter. Variable names  (and method names) are 'camelCase', class names are 'CamelCase'. You can see that the formatter writes your variable names in blue because it believes them to be a class name.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a bit messy, so lets go through it

1) Firstly in your GameViewController.swift you should set this property before calling the first scene

```
 skView.showsPhysics = true
```

to help you visually see your physics body when testing.

2) Dont use NSTimers for SpriteKit games, use SKActions.waitForDuration instead.

```
let timerAction1 = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
let timerAction2 = SKAction.runBlock(spawning1)
let timerSequence = SKAction.sequence([timerAction1, timerAction2])
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(timerSequence))
```

If you need to invalidate the timer at some point during gamePlay than simply give the runAction a key

```
  runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(timerSequence), withKey: "SpawnTimer")
```

and than remove it like so

```
 removeActionForKey("SpawnTimer")
```

At first glance this might seem  more code but trust me, its is a better way for spriteKit games. NSTimers dont pause when you pause your scene or they might cause issues on scene transitions. Always better to use spriteKit APIs as much as possible.

3) On some sprites you are force unwrapping the physics bodies

```
 ....physicsBody!.affectedByGravity....
```

use a ? instead.

```
....physicsBody?.affectedByGravity....
```

In general in Swift when you are dealing with optionals, like the physicsBody in this case, always use a ? whenever the compiler allows you too.

4) On some of your bodies you are setting physics properties before you are actually give the object a physics body

```
    BlueSquare.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    BlueSquare.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    BlueSquare.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20) // WRONG SPOT
```

It should look like this

```
    BlueSquare.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
    BlueSquare.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    BlueSquare.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
```

Now to the actual problem I believe your issue is with your scene size. If you are not scaling your scene to fit the device than the physics border you gave to the scene will not be the size of what you expect. The default scene size (GameScene.sks) is 1024x768 (iPad portrait resolution). You game is in landscape mode and on an iPhone so your scene will be cropped/strechted. 
To read more about scene scale modes check these articles

http://blog.infinitecortex.com/2014/01/spritekit-understanding-skscene-scalemode/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/49695/sprite-kit-tutorial-making-a-universal-app-part-1

I answered a similar question recently in regards to scene size, it might also help you

[How to change SKscene size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255593/how-to-change-skscene-size/36261147#36261147)

As a further side tip if you are learning swift it is good practice to follow the documentation, so for example your properties like BlueSquare should not start with a capital letter. Only classes, structs and protocols should start with Capital letters.

Hope this helps