# SpriteKit Positioning and containing a button

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to constrain and position a game center button to the top left and make it constrained for every device, how do I do this. I am really new to sprite kit.

```
 let gameCenterBtn = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Game-Center-icon.png")
        gameCenterBtn.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
        gameCenterBtn.name = "gameCenterButton"
        gameCenterBtn.position = CGPointMake(320, 730)
        gameCenterBtn.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width  , y: self.frame.height  )
```

For example how do I make a position a node and make it work for any device?

I figured it out. The code below works.

```
gameCenterBtn.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 188 , y: CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Scene cropping is still happening as I said in my old answer I deleted.

Open a brand new Xcode game template and paste your code with a position like this

```
 gameCenterBtn.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - (gameCenterButton.size.width / 2)  , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
```

and run on all the simulators to see what happens.

On iPads you see half the image on the right and on iPhones you only see 1/4.

Now go the the GameViewController and change the scene scale mode to ResizeFill and see what happens. You sprits will be at the same spot on all devices but you will have to readjust the image size.

This is how you set the scene size.

[How to change SKscene size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255593/how-to-change-skscene-size/36261147#36261147)

Comment: I updated my answer again, I am confusing my self now.